# OpenXML PPT table gets created on foreground, making the slide title and other texts go in background

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-table

I have a scenario in which there are {placeholder Tags} in a PowerPoint template, which gets replaced by a table. The problem is the table gets created in the foreground, making the slide title and other texts before tag goes in the background. I want to start the table from wherever the tag is present.

I tried calculating the slide positions and placing the table from the position wherever the placeholder tag is present, but still it overlaps.

Comment: PowerPoint has a feature called "tags" but I don't think that's what you're using. Please describe exactly what  you mean by {placeholder Tags}.  In any case, you might be able to pick up the original placeholder's Z-order value, then when you've added the table, repeatedly send it backwards until its Z-order matches the original placeholder's.